# Modify post template on Divi Theme

Tags: single

I'm using the Divi Theme on my site and i want to add some code on the posts template. I know i'm supossed to modify the single.php file, but anything i do on the file doesn't work. I even tried to just the leave the file blank, then leave it  almos blank except for a little "

## HELLO WORLD

" or something, but nothing happens.

I tried to do the same on the twenty-nineteen file and nothing happens there either.

Am i missing some step or something?

Comment: what theme is active in your admin area?

Comment: I'm using Divi, so Divi is activated.

Comment: I asked that because you've mentioned that you tried 2019 theme and even it didnt work. what exactly did you tried with 2019?

Comment: Modifying the single.php file

Comment: what was the outcome? more details you provide, I get better chance to help you out

Comment: In both themes just nothing happend, even when i just deleted the file from the ftp.

Comment: do you have any cache plugins/cloudflare or any cdn enabled?